# Fading in and out when text changes

Tags: javascript, css

I have a text div and several buttons that I would like the text to smoothly fade in and out when changing and/or hiding.

From checking Google and Stack Overflow, most of the answers suggest applying a CSS class of hide, then toggling that class while using a custom function to wait half a second before changing the text so the timing is perfect when the other text fades back in.

But I've read that can have problems with text that has span tags which mine have, and several people have also suggested there may be some plug-ins to simplify the process.

I can't find one, but is there a better method or a plug-in to handle this without replacing all of my code that updates text with custom functions?

I don't mind doing that if it's the only way, it just seems like there's likely a better/more intuitive option?

Comment: Hello Mate @TheNomadicAspie 

If you could provide the code that would be best for us to look into.

Comment: Please update the question to include a [mcve]

Comment: span tag does not make any problem if you are playing with container div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your statement:

> I have a text div and several buttons that I would like the text to
> smoothly fade in and out when changing and/or hiding.

Fade in / And Fade out can be achieved via CSS itself, or with Javascript or if you are using a JQuery library with that also. And text within buttons will not create any issues at all.

In **Pure CSS** you may require only two properties:

**transition** and **opacity** to be used in proper way.
This link can be helpful from CSStricks https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

In **JQuery** there you have **fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** functions which takes care of all the CSS internally and you only have to call these.

You may check this resource from W3Schools
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp

And Lastly even in pure Javascript the same can be achieved, depending on the requirement you have.